# How to compute a grouped, running calculation in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have records like below.

```
Employee        DateTime         Project      HoursWorked
Ralph          10/19/16 7:00     A                   5
Ralph          10/19/16 12:00    B                   5
Ralph          10/19/16 17:00    C                   5
Betty          10/19/16 8:00     A                   9
Betty          10/20/16 9:00     A                   6
Betty          10/20/16 15:00    B                   3
```

I need to compute Regular Hours and OT Hours.
For each employee, for each day, in datetime order, the first 8 hours are Regular Hours, then they are OT Hours.
Note: Project does NOT come into use for this computation; it explains why there can be multiple time entries per day.

Desired output:

```
Employee      DateTime           Project      HoursWorked              RegHrs      OTHrs
Ralph          10/19/16 7:00      A                    5                5            0
Ralph          10/19/16 12:00     B                    5                3            2
Ralph          10/19/16 17:00     C                    5                0            5
Betty          10/19/16 8:00      A                    9                8            1
Betty          10/20/16 9:00      A                    6                6            0
Betty          10/20/16 15:00     B                    3                2            1
```

How do I write SQL to do this? I am guesing that this will require a cursor, but I have no experience writing such.

Thank you

Comment: sorry about my formatting.

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you want to write the code for you?

Comment: If you're in 2012 or newer, just look up windowing functions, `sum(HoursWorked) over (partition by Employee order by DateTime)`